# AWS Cognito for Angular website authentication.. Attributes did not conform to the schema: email: The attribute is require

Tags: amazon-cognito, angular8

I am trying to register user with AWS Cognito by passing email and password, But i receive the below error

{code: "InvalidParameterException", name: "InvalidParameterException", message: "Attributes did not conform to the schema: email: The attribute is required↵"}
code: "InvalidParameterException"
message: "Attributes did not conform to the schema: email: The attribute is required↵"
name: "InvalidParameterException"
**proto**: Object

Code for sign up:

```js
 register(email, password) {
    
    const attributeList = [];
   
    return Observable.create(observer => {
      userPool.signUp(email, password, attributeList, null, (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log("signUp error", err);
          observer.error(err);
        }

        this.cognitoUser = result.user;
        console.log("signUp success", result);
        observer.next(result);
        observer.complete();
      });
    });

  }
```

Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was resolved by adding the attributes as below.

This is my method for registration this works fine with Cognito in angular 8

```
register(email, password) {

    const attributeList = [];
    attributes: {
      email
  };

    return Observable.create(observer => {
      userPool.signUp(email, password, attributeList, null, (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log("signUp error", err);
          observer.error(err);
        }

        this.cognitoUser = result.user;
        console.log("signUp success", result);
        observer.next(result);
        observer.complete();
      });
    });
```

Comment: Where this line is added, can you provide code wrapping your answer ?

Comment: I have updated my answer with the registration method. Please take a look